# How can I determine if outcome variables depend on two input variables in SPSS?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spss, normality-assumption

Using SPSS, I'm trying to determine if values for two independent variables (distance, tide) affect outcome concentrations of 5 compounds (dependent variables), which are listed below.  Is there a recommended way for determining this?

Edit to add, I have added the variable salinity which is dependent with respect to distance but not tide - it may be an independent variable with respect to the compounds being studied and may explain some of the trends in a way tide cannot since it's not simply binary. My goal remains the same, but now I have 3 independents w/r to my dependents. My PI suggested a Mann-Whitney U test for comparing the tides, but I feel like a test that looks at the dependents in terms of all 3 independents individually and together would be more helpful and concise. I don't really know how to properly calculate and store statistical results.

[image: Here is a new table with a new variable, salinity]

Comment: Yes, you can use linear regression in SPSS to regress each of the concentration variables on distance and tide.  Thus, 5 regression runs, where the first regression model is $y_{Amm} = b_0 + b_1 tide + b_2 distance$.

Comment: @user0123456789 what if my variables aren't linearly related? As you can see from the table, the distributions are somewhat erratic - that may be due to outliers that will get excluded, but I just tried plotting distance vs. some of those variables in Excel and even without the outliers the R2 values are still low. Obviously it's fine if it turns out not related because that's how science goes sometimes, but I'm worried about using the wrong analysis. I'm not sure.

Comment: If outliers are an issue, you can assign ranks to the values within each column, and use those, or see if SPSS has "quantile" or "median" regression.  For non-linearity you could either use derivative-based non-linear regression if you know the non-linear function to be fit, or fit e.g. polynomial or various functions to the assumed shape/distribution.